# SQL Azure V12 BACPAC import error. "Could not read schema model header information from package. The model version '3.5' is not supported

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

We take bacpacs of our Azure V12 database every night and restore locally using the command

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\120\DAC\bin>.\SqlPackage.exe /a:Import /sf:C:\1.bacpac /tdn:db1
>   /tsn:server1

As of 8 Nov 2016, this command has started failing with :

> *** Error importing database:Could not read schema model header information from package. The model version '3.5' is not supported.

This looks similar to a previous problem we had with this process back in April [SQL Azure V12 BACPAC import error: “The internal target platform type SqlAzureV12DatabaseSchemaProvider does not support schema file version '3.3'”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36754023/sql-azure-v12-bacpac-import-error-the-internal-target-platform-type-sqlazurev1)

That time is was due to a scoped configuration option of maxdop.  This time it appears to be another new configuration option which has just appeared (from the model.xml):

`<Property Name="TemporalHistoryRetentionEnabled" Value="False" />`

Why has this property seemingly randomly appeared in the model.xml ?

Comment: As a workaround seems, that running `ALTER DATABASE [dbname] SET TEMPORAL_HISTORY_RETENTION  ON` is sufficient to revert the model back as that is the default value for new databases.  Dont believe that on its own this command does much except perhaps kick off a background job that periodical cleans up temporal tables.    if there aren't any then I assume it's not much of an overhead.

Comment: There is a more recent build here:https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54273 but that is still generating the same error with a bacpac downloaded on Jan 1 2017....a nice New Year present!

Answer (score 6):

I ran into the same issue.   There is a new data tier applications framework.

It took me a few hours to find it.......

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53876

I installed it and my imports from bacpac files with sqlpackage.exe work again.

Hope that helps!

ps.  I am on a 64 bit machine and had to install both the 32 and 64 bit framework upgrade.